# Short vedic mantras to thank surya, vaayu, prithvi, aakash, agni and jal?

Tags: scripture, vedas, mantras

I am interested in knowing if there are short Vedic mantras, probably one liners to thank:

- Surya (Sun)
- Agni (Fire)
- Prithvi (Earth)
- Aakash (Ether)
- Jal (Water)
- Vaayu (Air)

Comment: In vedic one.liners.difficult. can be in puranic

Comment: Yeah sure why not.

Comment: You originally asked about water in the question but it was changed later. Do you want to know about varuna, the lord of water or water, one of five elements? They are not same. There are mantras separate for water besides Varuna.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma thank mantras are for deities. Especially in the Vedas. Any way i have rolled it back...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sanskrit is a Dev Bhaashaa. So, you can create your own one liner mantras which will definitely be listened by deities.Also deities are worshiped and offered respect by saluting them, thanking them is not much famous practice in Sanatan Vaidik Dharma.  The mantras can be like this,

- Om Suryaaya Namaha
- Om Agni Devaaya Namaha (om agnaye namah)
- Om Prithvi Devyai Namaha (om prithivyai namah)
- Om Antariksha Devaaya Namaha (om antarikshaya namah)
- Om Varunay Namaha
- Om Vayu Devaaya Namaha

One thing must be kept in mind that gods are pleased by devotion and satvik karmas, along with mantras.

> Coming to the topic, if one has mastered beejmantra science, then he can make mantras more effective by using the beejmantras. 
>   For example, if you add beejas like **hraam** **hrim** to above Surya mantra i.e. **Om Hraam Hreem Saha Suryaaya Namaha** you can attract the deity's attention effectively.
>   The logic is that, beejmantras are like nicknames when called one gives attention more quickly.
>   **One thing must be kept in mind that one has to be careful about using beejmantras as they have immense energies in them**
>
> Most abundant practice is that one must take diksha of his Ishta Devta mantra by a good Guru with a strong spiritual lineage. 
>   **Such mantras can change one's life positively beyond our imagination**.

Hope it helped...

Comment: One can also add beejas, om LaM prthivyai namah; om vaM jalaya namah, raM agnaye namah; om yam vayave namah; om ham akasaya namah; om am atmaya namah; Om.

Comment: Very nice suggestion. They are the beejmantras of these tatvas.

Comment: This is the vedic worship of respective gods like surya agni vaayu prithivi and varuna etc... Highly recommend in Vedas

Comment: Hmmm, true. I have heard that Tantra practices performed to control or please astral entities like Yakshas, Gandharwas, Kinnaras are strongly prohibited in Vedas. There is a huge junk over internet about such things. People are being misleaded to make money.

Comment: Am little confused as to which ones to use the normal ones or the ones using beejmantras? Are there any pre-requirements for using beejmantras? @Deepeshkumar

Comment: You can go for any of the types of mantras, but take care that you pronounce them properly. Also find a guru who will offer you diksha of mantras. Chanting without guru and diksha/initiation is not recommended in shastras.